# Get folder from file chooser button pygtk

Tags: application-development, pygtk

i want to get the location of the folder that is selected by a `filechooserbutton` in `pygtk`... how can i do this?

i connect the `current folder changed` signal from `filechooser` but the signal is emitted twice so i get the name of the folder twice...

i don't know what signal to connect... can i do something with properties?
any idea will be usefull... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `gtk.FileChooserButton` implements the [`gtk.FileChooser`](http://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtkfilechooser.html) interface. This means you can just use those methods on your button. `get_current_folder()` is probably the one you need.

Comment: which signal is better to connect? for using the `gtk.FileChooser` i must one, but i have only the `gtk.FileChooserButton` ... i must create a `gtk.FileChooser` in glade and then use the `builder.get_object()` ?

Comment: You don't need to create a `gtk.FileChooser`, the `gtk.FilechooserButton` implements its interface, which means you can use those methods, signals and properties. Do you really need signals? Usually you just retrieve the selected folder with the above mentioned `get_current_folder()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I was having issues trying to get the currently *selected* folder in the file chooser, instead of the currently browsing folder, and had to use `get_filename()` with the "selection-changed" signal for this.